# How to make a class with List<> member immutable?

Tags: c#, immutability

For example

```
class School
{
    public List<Student> Students {get; private set;}
}
```

Here `School` is not immutable because the getter `Students` is a mutable collection. How to make the class immutable?

Comment: You could expose an [immutable list](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e78dcd75.aspx) instead.

Comment: What do you want to restrict? Initialization of collection or items added in the collection?

Comment: Depends exactly what you mean by immutable. Do you want to prevent data encapsulated within each student from being changed also?

Comment: @vendettamit For both initialization of collection and items in the collection.

Comment: @user1899020 Look at the poke's answer. It's the way to go.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could just expose [an immutable list](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e78dcd75.aspx) instead:

```
class School
{
    private readonly List<Student> _students = new List<Student>();

    public ReadOnlyCollection<Student> Students
    {
        get { return _students.AsReadOnly(); }
    }
}
```

Of course doing this still has no impact on the `Student` objects, so to be completely immutable, the `Student` objects would need to be immutable to.

Comment: Good point. Deep immutability faces similar issues to deep copying

Comment: @BradThomas How to implement deep copying in c#? There is no copy constructor in C#.

Comment: You can serialize or apply copy all the way through the hierarchy, this can be relatively simple or complex, depending on your types. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/129389/how-do-you-do-a-deep-copy-an-object-in-net-c-specifically

Answer (score 4):

Simply make your backing field a private field and make the getter of the public property return a read-only version of the list.

```
class School
{
    private List<Student> students;

    public ReadOnlyCollection<Student> Students
    {
        get
        {
            return this.students.AsReadOnly()
        }

        private set;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd personally prefer @poke's answer because the public property clearly reflects the readonly-ness of the collection.