# Want to avoid returning writable references inside of a complex read-only class (game state)

Tags: c#, oop, game-development

I'm writing a little game, and the game has a `State` class to keep track of game state. The `State` class is only intended to be modifiable by `Command`s (command pattern). The `State` class includes lists of other classes - e.g. a `Faction` class, which contains members like resources, a list of owned `Unit`s, etc.

How can I make the deep innards of `State` readable from other classes, without also leaking writable references inside of `State` itself?

Currently, I have specialized getters like `State.GetOwnerOfUnitAtLocation(x)`, which only return safe values (`int factionid` etc.), but I am beginning to need a lot of these, and the class is getting really unwieldy. I would prefer to have those methods in more appropriate locations (`Map.Units.GetOwner(x)` or something), but I don't know how to expose the internals of `State` to other classes in a safe way.

Relatedly, `Command` is an interface that currently lives inside of the `State` class, along with all the actual commands that implement it, so that it can modify private members of `State`. Is there a better way to implement this?

---

Edit: A selection of code from `State` to illustrate the first issue:

```
public partial class State
{
    public int Turn {get; private set;} = 1;
    
    private Dictionary<Vector2, FactionsMgr.Faction> _unit_map = new Dictionary<Vector2, FactionsMgr.Faction>();

    public int GetUnitRemainingMobility(Vector2 pos)
    {
        if (IsUnitAt(pos))
        {
            FactionsMgr.Faction owner = _unit_map[pos];
            int taken_movement = owner.units[pos]._taken_movement;
            int max_mobility = UnitsMgr.GetMaxMobility(owner.units[pos].type);
            return max_mobility - taken_movement;
        }
        else
        {
            GD.Print("Warning: GetUnitRemainingMobility asked for unknown unit: ", pos);
            return -1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain, with the help of some code, exactly how exposing `Map.Units.GetOwner(x)` is "not safe"?

Comment: @OlivierRogier `State` consists of private members. For example: `private List<Factions.Faction> _factions; private Dictionary<Vector2, Factions.Faction> _unit_map;` (simplifying slightly to fit into a comment).

Comment: @Sweeper, I'm unsure I understand your question. What I'd like to do is to expose the internals of `State` in a read-only (this is what I mean by safe) way to other classes, such as `Map`. Currently, `Map` cannot see inside of `State` without calling on `State`'s very many custom getter methods, which return by value.

Comment: Yep you understood my question correctly. One solution is to just write an read-only interface for each of the mutable things in `State`, like how `IReadOnlyList` is the read-only version of `IList`. Expose the read-only interfaces, and keep the implementations private, only accessible by the inner class `Command`. If you show some code of `State`, I can show you how you'd do this exactly.

Comment: @Sweeper I've pulled out some code from `State` for you - is this helpful to get an idea of the current implementation?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there an easy way to make an immutable version of a class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26105608/) and [How do I create an immutable Class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/352471/) and [How to make a class with List<> member immutable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37169470/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `FactionsMgr.Faction` is mutable, let's suppose that it has writable properties like this:

```
class Faction {
    public int Foo { get; set; }
    public string Bar { get; set; }
    public float Baz { get; set; }
    public SomeOtherMutableThing AnotherThing { get; set; }
}
```

You should create a corresponding read only interface for it, and make `Faction` implement it:

```
interface IReadOnlyFaction {
    // exclude all members that can change Faction's state
    int Foo { get; }
    string Bar { get; }
    float Baz { get; }
    IReadOnlySomeOtherMutableThing AnotherThing { get; }
}

interface IReadOnlySomeOtherMutableThing {
    // do the same thing there...
}

class Faction: IReadOnlyFaction {
    public int Foo { get; set; }
    public string Bar { get; set; }
    public float Baz { get; set; }
    public SomeOtherMutableThing AnotherThing { get; set; }

    // you need an explicit interface implementation here, unless you are using C# 9
    IReadOnlySomeOtherMutableThing IReadOnlyFaction.AnotherThing => AnotherThing;
}
```

Then, you can declare public members in `State` as of type `IReadOnlyFaction`, and delegate them to a private member of type `Faction`. The private member is also what the `Command` class will modify.

```
private Faction someFaction;
public IReadOnlyFaction SomeFaction => someFaction;
```

That is the general case. However, if you have *collections* of these mutable types, like your dictionary of `_unit_map`, you would need to do a bit more work.

You would still have a public read only member and a private mutable member, but the delegating process is less straightforward. You would need a [wrapper](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13602918/5133585).

```
private Dictionary<Vector2, FactionsMgr.Faction> _unit_map = new();

public IReadOnlyDictionary<Vector2, IReadOnlyFaction> UnitMap;

// ...

// in the constructor of State...

// using the ReadOnlyDictionaryWrapper class from the linked answer
UnitMap = new ReadOnlyDictionaryWrapper<Vector2, FactionsMgr.Faction, IReadOnlyFaction>(_unit_map);
```

Comment: If the `Faction` class contains a Dictionary of builtin types (e.g. int to int), how do I include that in the `IReadOnlyFaction` interface? If I use an `IReadOnlyDictionary` in the corresponding part of `IReadOnlyFaction`, then `Faction` gives an error because it is not implementing the interface's expected return type. Is this a matter of writing a custom `{get;}` for one or both?

Comment: @Quintus You would do a transformation similar to `SomeOtherMutableThing`, except that there is already a `IReadOnlyDictionary` built in, so you don't need to create a new interface. Use an explicit interface implementation in `Faction` to implement the `IReadOnlyDictionary` property, as they will have the same name.

Comment: So you'll need to add something like `IReadOnlyDictionary<int, int> IReadOnlyFaction.SomeDictionary => SomeDictionary;` in `Faction` to implement `IReadOnlyFaction`. @Quintus